# loop in headers and first column to return matching data

Tags: google-apps-script

need to lookup in headers and in first column to return the matching cell value. i tried the following code but it returns undefined. thanks in advance.

```
function getDatas(e) {
  var id = "SHEET_ID";
  var sheetname = "test";
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(sheetname).getRange("A1:X328").getValues();
  var headers = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(sheetname).getRange(1, 1, 1, 4).getValues()[0];
  var cols = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(sheetname).getRange(1, 1, 3, 1).getValues()[0];

  var ar = [];

    for(var i=0; i< headers.length; i++){
     if(headers[i] == "red") {
               for(var j=0; j< cols.length; j++){
                 if(cols[j] == "2") {

                   ar.push((data[i][j]));
                   return ar;

                 }
               }
    }
}
}
```

my sheet data:

x  |  blue  |  green |  red  |   white

1   -----------------------------------

2   ------------------- this ----------

3   -----------------------------------

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getDatas() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('test');
  var rg=sh.getRange("A1:X328");
  var data = rg.getValues();
  var headers = sh.getRange(1,1,1,4).getValues()[0];
  var cols = sh.getRange(1,1,3,1).getValues().map(function(r){return r[0]});
  var ar = [];
  headers.forEach(function(h,i){if(h=='red'){cols.forEach(function(c,j){if(cols[j]==2) {ar.push(data[i][j]);}});}});
  return ar;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cooper again.. this returns empty result

Comment: Yes. just figure it out by exchanging i with j.  THANK YOU PAL

Comment: Good.  Those array method loops can be tough to figure out.